# How do I find x as a function of x?

Tags: functions

Sorry for the title, I don't know how else to put this into words.

Basically I wanted to know how to get the result below:

[image]

I have no idea about why the graph is showing **X** as a diagonal line. How can X by itself be a line which is not constant?

Comment: The diagonal line is the line $y=x$. Where it meets the other line is where the $x$ values are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x=462+0.085x$$
$$(1-0.085)x=462$$
$$0.915x=462$$
$$x=\frac{462}{0.915}=\frac{30800}{61}$$

Comment: Ok. I guess I just lack very basic arithmetic knowledge. I'm having trouble visualizing how do you go from the first line to the second one.

Comment: From the first equation, substract $0.085x$ to both sides and note that $$x-0.085x=(1-0.085)x$$

Comment: Great! I see it now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

Here you want to solve $$x=462+0.085x$$
There are two equations $y=x$ and $y=462+0.085x$.

Solving for $x=462+0.085x$ is equivalent to determining the solutions for the system $$y=x \text{  (Denoted by Blue Line)  }$$

&

$$y=462+0.085x\text{  (Denoted by Red Line)  }$$

The point of intersection of those two lines is your solution.
Now we proceed to find the solution.
$$(1-0.085)x=462$$
$$0.915x=462$$
$$x=\frac{462}{0.915}=\frac{30800}{61}$$